Is "the book" mentioned in Daniel 12:1 the same as the Book of Life in Revelation?
Daniel 12:1 (NIV)

“At that time Michael, the great prince who protects your people, will arise. There will be a time of distress such as has not happened from the beginning of nations until then. But at that time your people—everyone whose name is found written in the book—will be delivered.

Revelation 20:12-15 (NIV)

12 And I saw the dead, great and small, standing before the throne, and books were opened. Another book was opened, which is the book of life. The dead were judged according to what they had done as recorded in the books.........15 Anyone whose name was not found written in the book of life was thrown into the lake of fire.

Revelation 21:27 (NIV)

Nothing impure will ever enter it, nor will anyone who does what is shameful or deceitful, but only those whose names are written in the Lamb’s book of life.


No, because Daniel was written first. But it's entirely reasonable to interpret the Revelation passages as drawing on the language of Daniel's prophecies.

@PeterKirkpatrick- thanks for your feedback. I've edited my question to clarify it. Hope it is now clear.

The phrase "book of life" appears just once in the OT -

Ps 69:28 - May they be blotted out of the Book of Life and not listed with the righteous.

... and many times in the NT -

Phil 4:3 - Yes, and I ask you, my true yokefellow, to help these women who have contended at my side for the gospel, along with Clement and the rest of my fellow workers, whose names are in the Book of Life.
Rev 3:5 - Like them, he who overcomes will be dressed in white. And I will never blot out his name from the Book of Life, but I will confess his name before My Father and His angels.
Rev 13:8 - All inhabitants of the earth will worship the beast—all whose names have not been written in the Lamb’s Book of life, the Lamb who was slain from the creation of the world.
Rev 17:8 - The beast that you saw—it was, and now is no more, but is about to come up out of the Abyss and go to its destruction. And those who dwell on the earth whose names were not written in the Book of Life from the foundation of the world will marvel when they see the beast that was, and is not, and yet will be.
Rev 20:12 - And I saw the dead, great and small, standing before the throne. And books were opened, and one of them was the Book of Life. And the dead were judged according to their deeds, as recorded in the books.
Rev 20:15 - And if anyone was found whose name was not written in the Book of Life, he was thrown into the lake of fire.
Rev 21:27 - But nothing unclean will ever enter it, nor anyone who practices an abomination or a lie, but only those whose names are written in the Lamb’s Book of Life.

Note that this "Book of Life" appears to be a list of the saved, but is distinct (see Rev 20:12) from the book of records used in the judgement.
In Dan 12:1, the saved are those written "in the Book" which, therefore, appears to be the Book of Life" as described elsewhere.  Heb 12:23 appears to also allude to this same set of saved names:

Heb 12:23 - and to the assembly, to the church of firstborn, having been enrolled in heaven, and to God, judge of all, and to the spirits of the righteous having been perfected

Even Moses appears to reference this Book of Life in -

Ex 32:32 - Yet now, if You would only forgive their sin.... But if not, please blot me out of the book that You have written.”

Others arrive at the same conclusion such as the Cambridge commentary:

(Dan 12:1) written in the book viz. of life, the register of the living: in Psalm 69:28 (cf. Psalm 87:6, Exodus 32:32) applied to the register of
living members of the Theocratic community, which God is represented
as keeping.


Thank you for providing all the relevant references. They are helpful.

The Bible book entitled "Daniel" is one of many that comprise the ancient Hebrew scriptures. In chapter 12 verse 1 Daniel is writing about a prophecy of a future time when Michael, the great angelic prince, will act. At that time a book will be opened, with the names of God's delivered people written inside. Obviously, the Bible book called "Daniel" is not that book.
The Hebrew scriptures make just a few references to a heavenly record with such names in it. It is safe to think of that book already being in progress of listing names, long before Daniel, and continuing right until the time of the end, in the book of Revelation. As what the Apostle John wrote down refers to a heavenly Book of Life, "Revelation" is obviously not that book.
In Revelation chapter 20, there are books other than the Book of Life mentioned. 'Books' plural are stated - those which contain the deeds of all who have been resurrected, who are now being judged as to their eternal outcome. Then comes mention of the Book of Life. So, the resurrected dead are judged according to their deeds as recorded in various books, then the Book of Life is opened, and if their names are not found in it, they are cast into the eternally burning lake of sulphuric fire.
So, when Revelation 21:27 then speaks of those who are brought into the heavenly New Jerusalem, they are contrasted favourably with those who are kept out. Those who are welcomed in are "they which are written in the Lamb's book of life." This means that the Book of Life is synonymous with the Lamb's Book of Life. But the other books wherein peoples' deeds are recorded are distinct records.
What about the book mentioned by Daniel, then? Where does that heavenly record fit in? Given that 12:1 states "There will be a time of distress such as has not happened from the beginning of nations until then" (during Michael's action) and that the Revelation time of distress matches that perfectly (only, with much more detail, see Rev. ch. 16) then, yes, the book mentioned in Daniel 12:1 is the same Book of Life, not least because it is never mention in the plural. It is always singular: the Book of Life.

Your analytical answer is thorough and highly enlightening. Thanks!

Answer
“the book” mentioned in Daniel 12:1 is the same as the Book of Life in Revelation.
Explanation
We see the same Book throughout the Bible, as follows:

“And now if You will, lift up their sin. And if not, I pray, blot me
out from Your book which You have written. And Jehovah said to
Moses, Whoever has sinned against Me, I will blot him from My
book” (Exo 32:32-33).

[Notice carefully that this Book is Jehovah’s Book which He Himself wrote. When we come to the New Testament, we will see whose Book this is and who blots out names from it!]

“You know how troubled I am; you have kept a record of my tears.
Aren't they listed in your book?” (Psalms 56:8; GNB).


“Blot them out from the Book of Life; yea, let them not be written
with the righteous” (Psalms 69:28).


“Then those fearing Jehovah spoke together, each man to his neighbor.
And Jehovah gave attention and heard. And a Book of Remembrance
was written before Him for those who feared Jehovah, and for those
esteeming His name” (Malachi 3:16).


“But stop rejoicing in this, that the evil spirits submit to you. But
rather rejoice that your names are written in Heaven” (Luke
10:20).

[Definitely in Heaven the names of the saints will be written in the Book of Life]

“And I also ask you, true yoke-fellow, help those who struggled along
with me and with Clement in the gospel, and the rest, fellow-workers
with me, whose names are in the Book of Life” (Phlp 4:3).


“The one overcoming, this one shall be clothed in white garments, and
I will not at all blot his name out of the Book of Life; and I
will acknowledge his name before My Father, and before His angels”
(Rev 3:5).

[In Exo 32:33, it is Yahweh who blots out the names of people. But here we see Jesus blotting out the names! Is Jesus Yahweh?!]

“And all those dwelling in the earth will worship it, those of whom
the names had not been written in the Book of Life of the Lamb
having been slain from the foundation of the world” (Rev 13:8).

[In the Old Testament, we saw that this Book is called Jehovah’s Book. Here in the New Testament, but, we see this Book as the Book of the Lamb! Isn't Jesus Yahweh?!]

“And all profaning may not at all enter into it, or any making an
abomination or a lie; but only the ones having been written in the
Book of Life of the Lamb” (Rev21:27).


“And if anyone takes away from the Words of the Book of this prophecy,
God will take away his part from the Book of Life, and out of the
holy city, and of the things having been written in this Book” (Rev
22:19).

So right from Moses the first writer of the Scripture to John, the last writer, we see the Book of Life of Yahweh/Lamb mentioned.
The OP’s References

“And there shall be a time of distress, such as has not been from
the being of a nation until that time. And at that time, your people
shall be delivered, everyone that shall be found written in the
Book” (Daniel 12:1).

Here, the “time of distress” that has never occurred until that time is a clear reference to the Great Tribulation or Jacob’s Trouble. This is clearly the end of the Age.
The same time is mentioned in Revelation 20:12. But verse 15 mentions about a later time.
Note:- There is a correction in the reading of Revelation 20:12 as given in the OP’s version.
The literal reading is as follows:

“And I saw the dead, the small and the great, standing before God. And
books were opened. And another Book was opened, which is the Book of Life. And the dead were judged out of the things written in the books, according to their works”.

OP’s version says differently: “The dead were judged according to what they had done as recorded in the books….”.
What is written in the Books are not what the dead had done!
But the dead are judged, according to their works, out of the things written in the Books.
In other words, the deeds of the dead are matched with what (rules) are written in the Books!
Other Scripture verses show that these Books, in plural, different from the Book of Life, are in fact the books of the Bible; what constitute the Scripture!
[Please refer to Revelation 22:19 in which John mentions “the Book of Revelation” as one of the Books in relation to “the Book of Life”!]
Conclusion
Daniel also mentions “the books”, in plural, “were opened” (Dan 7:10) and a singular, “the Book” (Daniel 12:1).
Revelation also mentions “the books were opened” and another singular “the Book of Life was opened” (Rev 20:12).
The Books are the same, the Book is the same and God is the same.
